# svg luminanceToAlpha reverse?

Tags: html, svg, reverse, alpha

Is there a way to reverse a luminanceToAlpha?

```
<feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"></feColorMatrix>
```

**From this:**
[image]

**To This**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well a fast way is to do this:

```
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 1 0
                                     0 0 0 1 0
                                     0 0 0 1 0
                                     0 0 0 0 1"/>
```

But a warning that the result will be a greyscale that won't match a greyscale conversion of the original (if the original was color) - because the Red/Green/Blue channels have very different contributions to luminance -> which is  0.30 * Red  +  0.59 * Green  +  0.11 * Blue. In other words, you're going to get a green-overweight, blue-underweight greyscale.